# I am not able to set session after login

Tags: php, html, session

Good after friends I am trying to lock my home page with password using session but I am not succeed when i put session on my congratulation.php file it doesnt work .......I am trying for 2 days here is my *loginscript*

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$username = '';
$password = '';
$userError = ''; 
$passError = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
  if($username === '9155499248' && $password === 'Ben 10'){
    $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:congratulation.php'); die();
  }
  if($username !== '9155499248')$userError = 'Invalid Username';
  if($password !== 'Ben 10')$passError = 'Invalid Password';
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
      <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge ,chrome=1'>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>   
     <title>Login</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
     <script src='js/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
     </head>
 <body>
    <div class='login'>
<h1><b>Login</b></h1>
     <form name='input' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
    <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='".$username."' id='username' name='username' />
    <div class='error'>".$userError."</div>
    <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='".$password."' id='password' name='password' />
    <div class='error'>".$passError."</div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large' name='submit' value='1'>Let me in.</button>
  </form>
  </div>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script> 

  </body>
</html>";
```

And this is my **congratulation.php**

```
<?php
session_start()
?>
    <html>
     <head> 
     <title>NALIN NISHANT</title> 
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head> 
     <body>
    <!--header--> <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.facebookpage100.net23.net/?id=facebook"><img src="nalin.jpg"/><b>NALIN</b><br><h6>your ip address is <? 

    echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 

    ?> stored for security <br>purpose</h6></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="https://www.facebookpage100.net23.net/?id=facebook">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com">Visit Our Site</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/@hackingworldtips">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Follow Us<i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Facebook</a></li>
                               <li><a href="https://www.nalinnishant.nn@gmail.com">Google+</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header><!--/header--><br>
        <img src="js/1.jpg" width="100%" height="550"/>
     <!--php-->
     <?php 
     $filename = "users.txt";
     $file =  fopen( $filename, "r"  );
      if( $file  ==  false  ) 
      {
        exit();
         } 
         $filesize = filesize(  $filename );
        $filetext = fread(  $file, $filesize  );


        fclose(  $file  );

       echo ( "congratulation nalin......... your server hacked new facebook data" );
       echo ( "File  size :  $filesize  bytes" );
       echo ( "<pre>$filetext</pre>" );
         ?>     
          <section id="testimonial" class="alizarin">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="center">
                            <br><br><br><div class="text-success"><h2>Buy Facebook Hacking Script</h2></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="gap"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <blockquote><center><?php
    echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
    echo "day is" . date("l");
    ?></center>
                                    <p>if you want to buy hacking script or phising script for facebook then contact him directly on <a href="http://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Facebook</a>.</p>
                                    <small>Nalin Nishant</small>
                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        &copy; 2016 hackingworldtips.com. All Rights Reserved.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li><a href="http://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Follow Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://m.facebook.com/nalin.nishant.56">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a id="gototop" class="gototop" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a></li><!--#gototop-->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer><!--/#footer--><hr /><center><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></center><hr /><br>
     <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
       <script
                data-lang-en="{'text' : 'This website uses cookies to enhance your experiences.',
                'button' : 'I agree', 'more' : 'More information',
                'link' : 'http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm'}"
                data-expire="365"
                data-style="#cookieWarnBox a { color : orange }"
                type="text/javascript"
                id="cookieWarn"
                src="js/cookie-warn.min.js">
        </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: You don't have `session_start()` in the second file.

Comment: put session_start();  in all pages

Comment: I put session start but it still not working......what is the problem